# opencv conflict when trying to update all python packages using conda

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I have not used python for a while but I am going to heavily use it again very soon, so I decided to update all packages and typed

```
conda update -all
```

(I did all the installations using `anaconda`) I then get:

```
Fetching package metadata: ..
Warning: No packages found in current osx-64 channels matching: pymc >=2.3.3, skipping
Solving package specifications: ..
Error: Unsatisfiable package specifications.
Generating hint:

WARNING: This could take a while. Type Ctrl-C to exit.
|################################################################| 100%

Hint: opencv >=2.4.8 has a conflict with the remaining packages
```

From what I read in internet, this hint for `opencv` comes from the fact that `python 3.x` does not support `opencv` (?). However, I am on `Python 2.7.8`. I am on a mac 10.9.5 and my conda version

```
conda info
Current conda install:

         platform : osx-64
    conda version : 3.7.3
  conda-build version : 1.3.5
   python version : 2.7.8.final.0
 requests version : 2.4.3
 root environment : //anaconda  (writable)
  default environment : //anaconda
 envs directories : //anaconda/envs
    package cache : //anaconda/pkgs
     channel URLs : http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/osx-64/
                    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/osx-64/
      config file : None
is foreign system : False
```

So far all packages I have tried work and opencv seems to work. However, I would like to know what should I do to successfully update my installed packages with `conda`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That error message doesn't always mean that. It only means that if `python 3*` is mentioned in the error output.

In your case, some package you have installed depends on some earlier version of `opencv`. If you don't care what version of opencv you have installed, run

```
conda remove opencv
conda update --all
```

Comment: @asmeneur: 1st thanks for replying, you seem to be showing up in all my conda questions. I really like conda and its simplicity. Regarding to my question. I don't particularly care about the version, but I do care about having "A VERSION". I mean, I need `opencv`. Wouldn't the `conda remove opencv` remove `opencv` completely?

Comment: Assuming some other package depends on opencv (which based on your error message I'm assuming something does), `conda update --all` would reinstall it as a dependency.

Comment: @asmeneur: Hi again! So a few months later here I am with opencv + conda again. I want to update it and I type: `conda updat opencv` . This returns `# All requested packages already installed.` Is this meaning that the most updated conda supported version is already installed? Also, you wrote "Assuming some other package depends on opencv..." how can I verify that this the case? Finally, when I go for `conda install opencv` I get the message `The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:` and is numpy. So my final questions is: maybe the conflict updating opencv was with numpy? THANKS!

Comment: If you think this should be a different question I can always post it again as a question on its own. Overall, I'd simply like to have the most updated numpy and opencv packages possible...